# SQL Server 2012 Active Directory authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, sql-server-2012

I recently did a backup/restore of some catalogs from one server to another. Both servers are still up. User access to the servers is controlled via Active Directory and server roles. On the old server, there is no issue with continued user access. On the new server, however, we get log on errors. As near as I can tell (I may not have total access), the group set-up are the same on both servers. Where can I look for differences?

- Databases: SQL Server 2012 11.0.3000
- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP 1
- Testing: access was tested through Access (used only for the UI) and Excel connecting to SQL Server.
- User accounts: Access is done through a domain lookup, not a local account.

My hope for an answer is some direction in investigation. I am not a DBA. support process is moving too slow. It is a production issue so I am hoping to get a resolution quickly.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

What I found out was that the ad group must be in both the server security group as well as the catalog security. for the affected ad group, it was only in the catalog security group, not the server. thanks.